# Minimize a function

Tags: calculus, optimization, maxima-minima

I am trying to minimize the function $f(x) = \sqrt[x]{c\times x!}$ with respect to $x$($c>0$ is a constant), for $x>0$.
I have tried plotting the function to examine its behavior, and it looks to me that if we consider values of $x>0$, this function should have a global minimum. However, I don't know how to solve this minimization problem analytically, as the derivative is a rather strange looking function.

Comment: Is there meant to be a factorial? Are you using the $\Gamma$ function as an extension?

Comment: @themathandlanguagetutor Ideally,  I would like to get a general answer where the factorial notation is extended using $\Gamma$ function but I would also welcome any insights on the discrete case where $x$ is a natural number.

Comment: *Welcome to the site !* and thanks for the problem which is very interesting. I shall continue working it and edit if I am able to make better approximation. To give you an idea, for $c=100$, the minimum value is $6.44967$ while using the $x_0$ we have $6.44975$ ! Not too bad (for my age !). Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici Thank you very much! Using the logarithm and approximating the derivative as you did seems like an elegant idea and I will surely remember it for future use cases.

Comment: A lot of improvement !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @themathandlanguagetutor, consider
$$f(x)=\Big[c \,\Gamma (x+1)\Big]^{\frac{1}{x}}$$ and assume $c>0$. Using logarithmic differentiation, we have
$$\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)}=\frac 1 {x^2}\Big[x\, \psi (x+1)-\log (\Gamma (x+1))-\log (c) \Big]$$ So, we are looking for the zero of function
$$g(x)=x\,\psi (x+1)-\log (\Gamma (x+1))-\log (c)$$
$$g'(x)=x \,\psi ^{(1)}(x+1) \quad >0 \quad \quad\forall x >0$$ So, only one solution.

Now, $\big[x\,\psi (x+1)-\log (\Gamma (x+1))\big]$ is very linear as soon as $x > 1$ and a good approximation of it  is
$$x\,\psi (x+1)-\log (\Gamma (x+1))=x+\frac{1}{2} (1-\log (2 \pi  x))-\frac{1}{6
   x}+O\left(\frac{1}{x^2}\right)$$ So, keeping the first and second terms, as an *approximation*, we need to solve
$$x+\frac{1}{2} (1-\log (2 \pi  x))=\log(c) \implies x=-\frac{1}{2} W_{-1}\left(-\frac{e}{\pi  c^2}\right)$$ where $W_{-1}(.)$ is the second branch of Lambert function.

This would be the $x_0$ for Newton method.

Below are some results

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 c & x_0 & \text{solution} \\
 2 & 1.20556 &  1.39437 \\
 3 & 1.81582 &  1.93161 \\
 4 & 2.19930 &  2.29176 \\
 5 & 2.48314 &  2.56345 \\
 6 & 2.70899 &  2.78165 \\
 7 & 2.89662 &  2.96393 \\
 8 & 3.05712 &  3.12043 \\
 9 & 3.19732 &  3.25750 \\
 10 & 3.32177 &  3.37942 \\
 20 & 4.12296 &  4.16825 \\
 30 & 4.58111 &  4.62144 \\
 40 & 4.90271 &  4.94016 \\
 50 & 5.15051 &  5.18600\\
 60 & 5.35202 &  5.38606 \\
 70 & 5.52178 &  5.55470 \\
 80 & 5.66842 &  5.70041 \\
 90 & 5.79746 &  5.82868 \\
 100 & 5.91266 &  5.94323
\end{array}
\right)$$
To give an idea about the convergence, let us try for $c=10^4$; the iterates would be (with a ridiculous number of figures)
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
n & x_n \\
 0 & 10.819975929577196143 \\
 1 & 10.836092659850328733 \\
 2 & 10.836092115380538490 \\
 3 & 10.836092115380537870
\end{array}
\right)$$

So, we have a simple way to locate the minimum. Now, computing $f(x)$ does not make any problem.

**Edit**

Knowing the approximation $x_0$ we can improve a lot using one single iteration of Newton, Halley or Householder method. The simplest one will be
$$x_1=x_0-\frac {g(x_0)}{g'(x_0)}$$ The above table will now be
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 c & x_1 & \text{solution} \\
 2 & 1.39889 &  1.39437 \\
 3 & 1.93246 &  1.93161 \\
 4 & 2.29214 &  2.29176 \\
 5 & 2.56368 &  2.56345 \\
 6 & 2.78180 &  2.78165 \\
 7 & 2.96405 &  2.96393 \\
 8 & 3.12052 &  3.12043 \\
 9 & 3.25758 &  3.25750 \\
 10 & 3.37948 &  3.37942 \\
 20 & 4.16828 &  4.16825 \\
 30 & 4.62146 &  4.62144 \\
 40 & 4.94018 &  4.94016 \\
 50 & 5.18601 &  5.18600\\
 60 & 5.38607 &  5.38606 \\
 70 & 5.55470 &  5.55470 \\
 80 & 5.70042 &  5.70041 \\
 90 & 5.82869 &  5.82868 \\
 100 & 5.94323 &  5.94323
\end{array}
\right)$$

In other words, for practical applications, one single iteration of Halley or Householder methods will give the solution.

For illustration, for the case of $c=10^4$, here are the values ofhe first iterate as a function of the order of the method
$$x_1^{(2)}=\color{red}{10.836092}6598503$$
$$x_1^{(3)}=\color{red}{10.83609211}48391$$
$$x_1^{(4)}=\color{red}     {10.83609211538}11$$
$$x_1^{(\infty)}=\color{red}{10.83609211538054}$$

It must be noticed that $f(x_0)\times f''(x_0) <0 \quad \forall c$ which, by Darboux theorem, means that we shall face one overshoot of the solution along the path to convergence. At the opposite $f(x_1)\times f''(x_1) >0 \quad \forall c$ which will avoid it.

Comment: Well it's a very instructive answer .I have corrected a little typo .

Comment: @ErikSatie. Thanks. Amazing problem, isn't it ?